# Discord.py: Guild.members returns only the current bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

First of all, yes, I have read the other threads about this topic. But surprise it doesn't work as expected.
I want to overrite the original class, so I didn't use

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Instead I want to work with this kind:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
        def __init__(self, **options):
            super().__init__(**options)
            [...]

client = MyClient()
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

In  `__init__` or `on_ready()` I can set `discord.Intents.members = True` but this only  fixes the `guild.fetch_members()`, `guild.members` still returns only the current bot.
I would be happy for any help!

Bests

Comment: You shouldn't setup intents inside the `on_ready` event, can you please add how are you instantiating your `MyClient` class? And how are you actually enabling the intents?

Comment: Thanks for your note I updated my previous code. Acctually your last question is mine. Itried it with ```discord.Intents.members = True``` in the init-method of MyClient(). But as stated this only helps with guild.fetch_members()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just gotta pass the intents into your client constructor;

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
```